# Creating IF statement with multiple conditions that WORKS

Tags: excel, if-statement

Can someone spend a little time going through a relatively easy IF statement with me with multiple conditions?

This isn't the code, just trying to get my head around the criteria I have/need:

```
IF L2 = "-" or "blank" P2 = "-" or "blank" Q2 = "blank" or > 0 & T2 says "impact radius" THEN "not due"
However, IF T2 says "xxl" THEN "due"
```

Tried everything I can to make this work - it seems pretty simple, but I can't get it to do anything!

Comment: (this isn't the code, just trying to get my head around the criteria I have/need): 

   IF L2 = "-" or "blank" 
P2 = "-" or "blank"
Q2 = "blank" or >0 
& T2 says "impact radius" 
THEN "not due"

However,

   IF T2 says "xxl"
THEN "due"

Comment: Had to post the rest in a comment as it says it couldn't post as code wasn't correct - if it was correct, I wouldn't be posting - haha!

Comment: Please, post your relevant code in question.

Comment: That's the thing - i'm really struggling to make the code do anything.

Comment: Please edit your question according to the following guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve (also, it would be nice to know what programming language we're talking about)

Comment: This is the first time i've used this or anything like it - it's just a relatively simple excel question...I didn't realise there were guidelines to posting a help question!

Comment: Now you realize...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(OR(L2="-",L2="blank"),OR(P2="-",P2="blank"),OR(Q2="blank",Q2>0),T2="impact radius"),"not due",IF(T2="xxl","due",""))
```